# How to print path to the current Zone in zone.js

Tags: javascript, angular, zone.js

I'm experimenting with zones ([zone.js](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/)) and I realized I don't know what's the best way to print all the zones from root to the current zone that threw an error.

For example this code uses two nested callbacks with `setTimeout()` and then calls a function called `failedFunc()` that throws an error:

```
require('zone.js');

function failedFunc() {
  throw new Error("it's broken");
}

let rootZone = Zone.current;

function func1() {
  let zoneA = rootZone.fork({name: 'zoneA'});
  zoneA.run(() => {
    setTimeout(() => func2());
  });
}

function func2() {
  let zoneB = Zone.current.fork({name: 'zoneB'});

  zoneB.run(() => {
    setTimeout(() => failedFunc());
  });
}

func1();
```

When I run this example it gives the following output:

```
/.../zone-test/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js:170
                        throw error;
                        ^
Error: it's broken
    at new Error (native)
    at failedFunc (/.../zone-test/zone_02.js:12:9) [zoneB]
    at Timeout.setTimeout (/.../zone-test/zone_02.js:28:22) [zoneB]
    at Zone.runTask (/.../zone-test/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js:166:47) [<root> => zoneB]
    at Timeout.ZoneTask.invoke (/.../zone-test/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js:416:38) [<root>]
    at Timeout.data.args.(anonymous function) [as _onTimeout] (/.../zone-test/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js:1590:25) [<root>]
    at ontimeout (timers.js:365:14) [<root>]
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:237:5) [<root>]
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:207:5) [<root>]
```

The correct path for the zone that threw the error is `<root>` => `zoneA` => `zoneB`.

However it's not obvious from the output. There's just `[root]` and `zoneB` and it doesn't mention the `zoneA` which is confusing. I guess this is because the `zone.js`'s monkey patch only adds zone info to the lines in the call stack. So when I'm using `setTimeout()` than creating `zoneA` doesn't correspond to any line in the output and that's why I don't see it anywhere.

Nonetheless, I can print the path to the current zone by iterating all it's parents but this means I need to know where the error first happened and add the following code to it (which would be very tedious in practice):

```
function failedFunc() {
  let zone = Zone.current;
  let zones = [];
  while (zone) {
    zones.push(zone.name);
    zone = zone.parent;
  }
  console.log(zones);

  throw new Error("it's broken");
}

// ...
```

Now when I run this I'll get what I need:

```
[ 'zoneB', 'zoneA', '<root>' ]

/.../zone-test/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js:170
                        throw error;
                        ^
Error: it's broken
    at new Error (native)
```

So I'm wondering how to use zone.js in practice and in a way that it's easier than this.

Comment: Zonejs uses the concept of ZoneFrame to get such output.https://github.com/angular/zone.js/blob/v0.8.5/lib/zone.ts#L1656-L1676. You can write your own version of global.Error.As i noticed this output is changed very often. Check last commit https://github.com/angular/zone.js/commit/681a01788e2097b1d3751a07afae626deb427a60

Comment: I think you're looking for longStackTraceZone, I changed your code a little bit and created jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Oski/ye0yz8c4/2/ I couldn't find `long-stack-trace-zone` so I just pasted it in HTML section. `Zone.current` always returns the zone in which it's being run

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To obtain the full stacktrace of your `zone` you have to use [long-stack-trace-zone](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/blob/master/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js)

Please note, that I'm throwing an exception, this is why you will see an error in my snippet. The question and the answer is about printing full stacktrace:

```js
function failedFunc() {
  throw new Error("it's broken");
}

function func1() {
  let zoneA = Zone.current.fork({
    name: 'zoneA'
  });
  zoneA.run(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      func2()
    });
  });
}

function func2() {
  let zoneB = Zone.current.fork({
    name: 'zoneB'
  });

  zoneB.run(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      failedFunc()
    });
  });
}

Zone.current.fork({
  onHandleError: function(parentZoneDelegate, currentZone, targetZone, error) {
    console.log(error.stack);
  }
}).fork(Zone.longStackTraceZoneSpec).run(func1);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zone.js/0.8.5/zone.min.js"></script>
<!--  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angular/zone.js/master/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.min.js -->
<script>
!function(t,a){"object"==typeof exports&&"undefined"!=typeof module?a():"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(a):a()}(this,function(){"use strict";function t(){return new Error(u)}function a(){try{throw t()}catch(a){return a}}function e(t){return t.stack?t.stack.split(i):[]}function n(t,a){for(var n=e(a),r=0;r<n.length;r++){var c=n[r];s.hasOwnProperty(c)||t.push(n[r])}}function r(t,a){var e=[a.trim()];if(t)for(var r=(new Date).getTime(),c=0;c<t.length;c++){var o=t[c],s=o.timestamp,f="____________________Elapsed "+(r-s.getTime())+" ms; At: "+s;f=f.replace(/[^\w\d]/g,"_"),e.push(h.replace(_,f)),n(e,o.error),r=s.getTime()}return e.join(i)}function c(t,a){a>0&&(t.push(e((new l).error)),c(t,a-1))}function o(){var t=[];c(t,2);for(var a=t[0],e=t[1],n=0;n<a.length;n++){var r=a[n];if(r.indexOf(u)==-1){var o=r.match(/^\s*at\s+/);if(o){h=o[0]+_+" (http://localhost)";break}}}for(var n=0;n<a.length;n++){var r=a[n],i=e[n];if(r!==i)break;s[r]=!0}}var i="\n",s={},f="__creationTrace__",u="STACKTRACE TRACKING",_="__SEP_TAG__",h=_+"@[native]",l=function(){function t(){this.error=g(),this.timestamp=new Date}return t}(),d=t(),k=a(),g=d.stack?t:k.stack?a:t;Zone.longStackTraceZoneSpec={name:"long-stack-trace",longStackTraceLimit:10,getLongStackTrace:function(t){if(t){var a=t[Zone.__symbol__("currentTask")],e=a&&a.data&&a.data[f];return e?r(e,t.stack):t.stack}},onScheduleTask:function(t,a,e,n){var r=Zone.currentTask,c=r&&r.data&&r.data[f]||[];return c=[new l].concat(c),c.length>this.longStackTraceLimit&&(c.length=this.longStackTraceLimit),n.data||(n.data={}),n.data[f]=c,t.scheduleTask(e,n)},onHandleError:function(t,a,e,n){var c=Zone.currentTask||n.task;if(n instanceof Error&&c){var o=r(c.data&&c.data[f],n.stack);try{n.stack=n.longStack=o}catch(i){}}return t.handleError(e,n)}},o()});
</script>
```